# How use rendertron with loopback 3 and angular 6?

Tags: angular, loopback, rendertron

I'm trying to use rendetron with loopback and angular 6

I create rendertron bootscript:

```
const rendertron = require('rendertron-middleware');

module.exports = function(app, res) {
  app.use(rendertron.makeMiddleware({
    proxyUrl: 'http://my-rendertron-instance/render',
  }));
  console.log(res);
};
```

And loopback serve static angular project in client

Comment: I'm sorry. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: When I check my site in prodcution I when I want to share a page https://fruitylab.fr/creations/detail/latelier84 any og:titile og:description and og:image works... 
And in my angular app in create SeoService who find the title and description from loopback req